# Regular expression ignore capturing group order

Tags: javascript, regex, swap, capturing-group

Please open following URL in chrome => https://regex101.com/r/rWLAOU/1/

Regex:

```
\b(f|fall|w|winter|s|spring|su|summer)\b\s*(?<!\d)(\d{4}|\d{2})(?!\d)
```

Test Strings:

```
Fall 2018
fall 18
2016 Fall
F2016
Fall2016
```

The Regular Expression I defined works fine for all the Test Strings except when capturing group order is swapped (2016 Fall or 16f or 18Su)
Is there a way in Regular expression to ignore ordering of capturing groups of your RegExp

Comment: `Please open following URL in chrome` Don't tell people go to an external site, post all the relevant code in your question.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Even if he posted regex we have to go to regex101 or something similar.

Comment: @revo The point is, if the link is broken in the future, the question will not be answerable or helpful to anyone. If the regex is in the question, this wouldn't happen.

Comment: @Sweeper Yes, I know what you are talking about but you didn't get my point. However in that *future* - which I don't think the future you are talking about is within next seconds - this probably got an answer or is closed. So need not to worry about *not being answerable*. This wouldn't be helpful to anyone either. I updated question to include regex.

Comment: Are you sure you wanted to ask about *JavaScript* RegExp flavor? There is no lookbehind there and your example implies you wanted to use it (`(?<=…)`).

Comment: @myf  : Yes, I'm asking for Javascript regexp flavor. "lookbehind" is supported ONLY in chrome. Anyways I have updated the regex in my original question without lookbehind approach. It would be great if someone can point how to swap order of capture groups. 
Thanks everyone!

Comment: You should explain what your real problem is. We see how the regex works, what exactly do you need? Why do you think you need the same group ordering? What should the final result look like for each of the supplied sample strings? Note your current regex (in this post) does not need a lookbehind, it is the same as [`\b(f|fall|w|winter|s|spring|su|summer)\s*(\d{4}|\d{2})(?!\d)`](https://regex101.com/r/rWLAOU/2). Also, why not use 4 groups and check which one matched to get the right values in the resulting array? See https://regex101.com/r/rWLAOU/3

Comment: @Wiktor Solution you posted works perfectly fine. Thank you for your answer. Basically requirement for the input strings I mentioned, regular expression should be able to give matching for semester and year irrespective of their order in input string. Year can be 2 or 4 digits. Both can be separated by 0 or more spaces.

Comment: I posted an answer, please consider accepting (if it worked for you) and upvoting (if you find it useful).

Answer (score 1):

You may use an alternation with two parts where the year and season are swapped and then grab only the matched captures:

```
\b(?:(f(?:all)?|w(?:inter)?|s(?:pring|u(?:mmer)?)?)\s*(\d{2}(?:\d{2})?)|(\d{2}(?:\d{2})?)\s*(f(?:all)?|w(?:inter)?|s(?:pring|u(?:mmer)?)?))\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rWLAOU/4)

I contracted your alternatives to make matching more efficient: all alternatives should only match at unique locations. Word boundaries seem to be enough for your case.

In JS, you may build the pattern dynamically:

```js
var strs = ['Fall 2018','fall 18','2016 Fall','F2016','Fall2016'];
var season = "(f(?:all)?|w(?:inter)?|s(?:pring|u(?:mmer)?)?)";
var year = "(\\d{2}(?:\\d{2})?)";
var p = new RegExp("\\b(?:" + season + "\\s*" + year + "|" + year + "\\s*"+ season + ")\\b","i");
var results=[], m;
for (var s of strs) {
  m  = s.match(p);
  if (m) {
    if (m[1]) {
      console.log(m[1],":", m[2]); 
    } else {
      console.log(m[3],":", m[4]); 
    }
  }
}
```